# Magento Product Insert Function

Tags: magento

I need to add a custom option to all products as they get saved. For that I need to find the function that inserts the products into the database, which I'm not able to find.

Please, any help would be appreciated.

thanx

Comment: which product ? which option? which database?

Comment: i just need to find the insert function for simple product.

Comment: You said that already. Please specify.

Comment: i need to find the default core insert function of magento which inserts the products into the database

Comment: what i wanted to do was  to add a custom option to the product automatically , so that i dont have to manually add a custom option for each product that is inserted and will be inserted , so for that i need to find the core insert function for a simple product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento's EAV system is pretty strung out among several files, so you won't find a single function that accomplishes what you want. If you did go looking for it, and changed it, you would also be changing the same save method that mostly every other object in Magento uses, which is probably not what you want.

To do what you want, try setting up an observer/listener on the events that catalog products use when saving, namely `catalog_product_save_before` or `catalog_product_save_after`. That way, you don't have to hack the framework.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

```
    $client = new SoapClient('http://www.magentolocal.it/api/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('productloader', '1234567890');

$sku = "123456";
$attrs['name'] = "Template #1";
$attrs['description'] = "This is the first template.";
$attrs['short_description'] = "This is the short description of the template";
$attrs['websites'] = array('1');
$attrs['price'] = "11.53";
$attrs['categories'] = array('35');
$attrs['images'] = array()

$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', '63', $sku, $attrs));
echo $result;
$client->endSession($session);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product#catalog_product.create?

Comment: well thats not quit what i am looking for im looking to find the core function inside "mage" which when i add a product from the backend inserts the product into the database.